# While UISearchBar is active,scrolling to UITableView app get crashes

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uisearchbar

My app works fine, but suddenly when I click on `UISearchBar` and without typing when I scroll down `UITableView` then app crashes with the following error:  `Thread1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

But when I click on `UISearchBar` and type some text, after that when I scroll down `UITableView` the app works fine, it does not crash.

Finally when I click on `UISearchBar` and type some text and remove all that text, after that when I scroll down `UITableView` the app works fine, it does not crash.

Error occurs in this function :

```
 func tableView(historyTableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = historyTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell;
        //self.historyTableView.scrollEnabled = true
        if(searchActive){
//...Error occurs over here ==>> Thread1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
            cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]  
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: can you show your full stack trace

Comment: Use exception breakpoint it will help you to figure it out that where its getting crash exactly.

Comment: This situation may occur when any error in your filtered array is there to the index where you are scrolling in tableview, check the filtered array elements.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that when you begin your active search, you are not reloading the table. I'm also guessing that `nunberOfRowsInSection:` doesn't handle the case of an active search. If those things are true, then calling `filtered[indexPath.row]` will crash your app anytime you scroll to a row greater than `filtered.count`

Comment: What does your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method look like?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have handled you `filtered` and `data` array in `numberOfRowsInSection` method too.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if(searchActive){

        return filtered.count

    }else{

        return data.count
    }
}
```

Now you have to just make your `searchActive` to `true` when you click on `UISearchBar`.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

By this way I've overcome from this problem.

```
func tableView(historyTableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = historyTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell;
        if(searchActive){
            if(searchBar.text=="")
            {
                //do nothing

            }else{
                cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
            }

        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Now app doesn't get crashes while scrolling, because I've handle this by add condition if seachbar is empty then do nothing.